# Syntax Highlighting in WMD Editor

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wmd-editor

Is there any open source version of WMD which is provided with syntax highlighting ability?

What If I wanted to use the exact SE WMD Editor version? Shouldn't it be open source too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the WMD editor used on this site at http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/